# Negative value format with in parentheses

Tags: php

normally php will output negative integer with this format `-1234`, how to it show in parentheses format `(1234)`

example:

```
$foo = 10 - 20;
// output: $foo = -10
// expected output $foo = (10)
```

Comment: Where in the world is that a valid format for a negative number?

Comment: Ah, fair enough. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_number I don't think there is a way to do this in PHP, though

Comment: @Pekka in excel spreadsheets a lot of the time it is notated in parenthesis.

Comment: To put that in context, it is standard in accounting ledgers and reports, to distinguish clearly from dashes in the text, or inadvertent marks. The Excel formatting option is to satisfy the pre-existing financial convention.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to make PHP do this automatically.

```
echo ($foo < 0 ? "(".abs($foo).")" : $foo);
```

is the shortest solution that comes to mind.

Comment: You should also use `abs()` on negative number

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion the easiest way is creating your own print function, out of the box with php this isn't possible.

```
function print_val($int){
    return ($int < 0) sprintf('(%d)', abs($int)) : $int;
}
```